# In php code is not run successfully. the error is "Invalid Operation Called"

Tags: php

```
     <?php 
    //getting the database connection
require_once 'DbConnect.php';

//an array to display response
$response = array();

//if it is an api call 
//that means a get parameter named api call is set in the URL 
//and with this parameter we are concluding that it is an api call 
if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

    switch($_GET['apicall']){

        case 'signup':

            //checking the parameters required are available or not 
            if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username','password','email','height','weight','gender','age'))){

                //getting the values 
                $username = $_POST['username']; 
                $password =$_POST['password'];
                $email = $_POST['email']; 
                $height = $_POST['height']; 
                $weight = $_POST['weight'];
                $gender = $_POST['gender'];
                $age = $_POST['age'];  

                //checking if the user is already exist with this username or email
                //as the email and username should be unique for every user 
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();

                //if the user already exist in the database 
                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'User already registered';
                    $stmt->close();
                }else{

                    //if user is new creating an insert query 
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, height, weight, gender,age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $username, $email, $height,$weight, $gender,$age);

                    //if the user is successfully added to the database 
                    if($stmt->execute()){

                        //fetching the user back 
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,id,username, email, height, weight, gender, age FROM users WHERE username = ?"); 
                        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($userid, $id,$username, $email, $height, $weight,$gender ,$age);
                        $stmt->fetch();

                        $user = array(                  
                            'id'=>$id,                       
                            'username'=>$username, 
                            'email'=>$email,
                            'height'=>$height,
                            'weight'=>$weight,
                            'gender'=>$gender,
                            'age'=>$age

                        );

                        $stmt->close();

                        //adding the user data in response 
                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'User registered successfully'; 
                        $response['user'] = $user; 
                    }
                }

            }else{
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'required parameters are not available'; 
            }


        break; 

            case 'login':
            //for login we need the username and password 
            if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username', 'password'))){
                //getting values 
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password']; 

                //creating the query 
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, email, height, weight, gender,age FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username, $password);

                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->store_result();

                //if the user exist with given credentials 
                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

                    $stmt->bind_result( $username, $email, $height, $weight, $gender, $age);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    $user = array(

                            'username'=>$username, 
                            'email'=>$email,
                            'height'=>$height,
                            'weight'=>$weight,
                            'gender'=>$gender,
                            'age'=>$age
                    );

                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Login successfull'; 
                    $response['user'] = $user; 
                }else{
                    //if the user not found 
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Invalid username or password';
                }
            }
        break;

        default: 
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
    }

}else{
    //if it is not api call 
    //pushing appropriate values to response array 
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
}

//displaying the response in json structure 
echo json_encode($response);



//function validating all the paramters are available
//we will pass the required parameters to this function 
function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

    //traversing through all the parameters 
    foreach($params as $param){
        //if the paramter is not available
        if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
            //return false 
            return false; 
        }
    }
    //return true if every param is available 
    return true; 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMABa.png)

the error is "Invalid Operation Called"

Please help me. I am trying to implement singup functionality in my android app using php and as i am not aware of php, i am not sure what is wrong.

How i do? thank you.

Comment: So if you get `Invalid Operation Called` then your `$_GET['apicall']` is neither `signup` nor `login`.

Comment: you type `apicall=sigup` in URL, and `sigup` not in the `case`

Comment: Thank very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your picture, you have a typo. You are setting your GET parameter `apicall` to `sigup` instead of `signup`. Correct that typo and your switch statement will fire on `case 'signup'` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That may be because you are not getting a match for a switch case. First of all please check the value of $_GET['apicall'] by using:

echo $_GET['apicall'];

Do this above if condition.
If you get this value then it may be easy to get a solution.

The parameter you are getting in $_GET['apicall'] is incorrect that is why its goes in else condition rather than if.